# Computed data in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I was doing a course at Vue Mastery and found such code:

```js
    export default {
      data() {
        const times = []
        for (let i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
          times.push(i + ':00')
        }
        return {
          event: this.createFreshEvent(),
          times,
          categories: this.$store.state.categories,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        createFreshEvent() {
          const user = this.$store.state.user
          return {
            organizer: user,
            attendees: []
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

- Why sometimes author uses inline code to generate data (times)?
- Why for next `data` property he uses method? Is there a difference?
- Why `data()` doesn't have only declarations and we don't generate all of above in `created()` life cycle hook?

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 and 3 it's better to ask the one who created to course. There is no real reason to do it like this. I wouldn't do it the way he does, but indeed use `created` or `mounted` method.

For question 2:

> In component’s data option must be a function, so that each instance
> can maintain an independent copy of the returned data object::

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 0):

By Vue's definition of `created` lifecycle hook: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created

> Called synchronously after the instance is created. At this stage, the
> instance has finished processing the options which means the following
> have been set up: data observation, computed properties, methods,
> watch/event callbacks. However, the mounting phase has not been
> started, and the $el property will not be available yet.

So generating data in `data()` will not trigger any related computed properties, watch/event callbacks. If you generate those data in `created` and your component has, for example, a watcher on `times`, there will be unneeded watch callbacks.

Btw, I am confused of the initialization of `categories` from `this.$store.state.categories`. Storing shared data from vuex in local `data` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Thinker `mapState` is more suitable if `categories` is read-only, i.e. this component only access `categories` for displaying purpose, not modifying. If there is attempt for changing values, then `mapState` is not enough and original code will violate Vuex's mutation rule: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html